# systemd show <service-name> --property=environment" shows only one value

Tags: linux, environment-variables, systemctl

I am working on a script to extract a specific environment variable - `CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY` defined in the unit for the service `confluent-server.service` and use that value in the script to perform other actions.

I tried `systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment` but it shows only the first `ENVIRONMENT=` value - `Environment=KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`.  There are 5 ENVIRONMENT variables defined for the service.  How do I list all 5 and extract the value of `CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY`.

I thought the original question was fully explaining the situation, but have added more details.

Below is the output of the command

```
`systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment`
```

This is the whole output. Modified the masterkey value, but format is same

```
Environment=KAFKA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jolokia.properties KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=abcdefghYRkHGYhKM4CRQOBVt9C9wKp8QAZ3i5Nzs=
```

@Thiru has already provided the answer.  And I have accepted it as it resolves the issue

Comment: it supposed to show all the values set for the property "Environment" but if that's not the case then maybe you can try something like this "systemctl show confluent-server.service | grep -i Environment"

Comment: Thanks @Thiru.  That works.  Actually, the original command also shows all of them, but it seems to go out of display hence showing only one.  When I captured the output in a file, I can see all. But it shows in a single line as `Environment=KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M KAFKA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jolokia.properties LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka`.  How can I extract the variable and value I need ?

Comment: The comment was becoming too long, hence removed other variables - I need to extract `CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY` which does show in the single line in the output and I need to extract that

Comment: maybe you can use awk to extract the values from the output. if you can share the whole output then i can help you with the awk command to extract the value

Comment: Thx. This is the whole output.  Modified the masterkey value, but format is same
`Environment=KAFKA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jolokia.properties KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=abcdefghYRkHGYhKM4CRQOBVt9C9wKp8QAZ3i5Nzs=`

Comment: You can try
 systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment | awk -F "CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=" '{print $2}'
(or)
you can split the lines using sed and then grep the value you need..

systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY

Comment: Thanks.  Both of them work.   Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Then I suggest you make the question match the answer ... as it stands (comments not withstanding) they seem largely unrelated.

Comment: I updated the question.  But don't understand what you mean by they seem unrelated. Can you please explain?   In the comments I just added the output of the command.     *This was the original question - I tried systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment but it shows only the first ENVIRONMENT= value - Environment=KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS. There are 5 ENVIRONMENT variables defined for the service. How do I list all 5 and extract the value of CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY.*    And the comments and the answer match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, here is the solution.

Using awk you can just filter the value you would want like below but note that it works fine only if the variable CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY output value is at the end of the line.

```
# systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment | awk -F "CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=" '{print $2}'
abcdefghYRkHGYhKM4CRQOBVt9C9wKp8QAZ3i5Nzs=
```

If the CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY value comes in the middle of the line.
example :

```
systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment
Environment=KAFKA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jolokia.properties KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms6g -Xmx6g -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80  CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=abcdefghYRkHGYhKM4CRQOBVt9C9wKp8QAZ3i5Nzs= KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka
```

Then the awk result would be as below which is not right . (of course using the awk we can further filter the value like this : awk -F "CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=" '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}')

```
systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment | awk -F "CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=" '{print $2}'
abcdefghYRkHGYhKM4CRQOBVt9C9wKp8QAZ3i5Nzs= KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka
```

Simple workaround is that we can simply split the lines using sed (replace space with new line /n) and then we can filter the value

```
systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment | sed 's/ /\n/g'
Environment=KAFKA_OPTS=-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
-javaagent:/opt/jolokia/jolokia.jar=config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jolokia.properties
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms6g
-Xmx6g
-XX:MetaspaceSize=96m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M
-XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50
-XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80

CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=abcdefghYRkHGYhKM4CRQOBVt9C9wKp8QAZ3i5Nzs=
KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties
LOG_DIR=/var/log/kafka
```

and finally do a grep

```
systemctl show confluent-server.service --property=Environment | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY
CONFLUENT_SECURITY_MASTER_KEY=abcdefghYRkHGYhKM4CRQOBVt9C9wKp8QAZ3i5Nzs=
```